# Is there a way to extend WSHttpBinding to allow SwA?

Tags: wcf, customization, wshttpbinding

Using WCF, can I create my own binding (based on WSHttpBinding) and use it manipulate the HTTP request so that I could add standard MIME attachments to it (SwA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not as far as I know.  Why are you not using [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM) ?